# Drinfeld associators expansion to higher weights

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, generating-functions, zeta-functions, hopf-algebras

Does anyone know where to get higher orders (for weight >10) expansion in Drinfeld associators. (the generating function for MZVs)
The answer might be in the form of (4.5) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3259.pdf.
(i.e. in terms of generators of the algebra e0, e1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3259.pdf or https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3053.pdf.
We can use the first order differential equation:

d/dz I(e0,e1)=(e0/z+e1/(1-z))I(e0,e1) or
d/dz I(e0,e1)=I(e0,e1)(e0/z+e1/(1-z))

And on evaluate z to 1 we get the result in both paper respectively. (Normalizing HPL({1},1)=0)

(Also Note:the above two have different convention)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try to modify it.